# Return formbuilder array from an Observable

Tags: angular, forms, typescript, observable

I need to return an array of FormControl for an array-type control.
But I need to know how many values come into my Observable to be able to mount these data.

**Here is the code:**

```
users$ = this._store.select(usersSelectors.getUsers);

createForm(): void {
    this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
        users: this.buildArray(),
    });
}

buildArray(): any {
    this.users$.subscribe((data) => {
        if (data) {
            const values = data.map(() => new FormControl(false));
            return this._formBuilder.array(values);
        }
    });
}
```

The reason is so that in HTML I can create dynamic checkbox with the users enabled for a certain action.

**component.html**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
  <label for="users">Users</label>
  <div id="users" class="row">
    <div class="checkbox" class="col-sm-4"
      formArrayName="users"
      *ngFor="let item of myForm.get('users').controls; let i = index" >
      <label class="checkbox-inline">
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i"> {{ users$[i] }}
      </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first of all, you're not returning an Observable. You're returning nothing (you didn't add any return statement in your function).

Also, if you added one, you would return a subscription, because you used `subscribe` in your function.

If you want to create a form array from your observable, here is how :

```
users$ = this._store.select(usersSelectors.getUsers);

createForm(): void {
  this.users$
    .pipe(
      filter(data => !!data),
      map(users => this._formBuilder.array(users.map(() => new FormControl(false))))
    )
    .subscribe(usersFormArray => this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      users: usersFormArray
    })
  });
}
```

You don't need another function, because this function does everything you wish.

You start by filtering the data : this is the equivalent of a condition. If there isn't any data, the subscribe won't be triggered.

Then, you map the observable value to return a form array.

Finally, you subscribe and create your form with the mapped value.

Comment: Okay, I understand, but what about HTML? How could I access the observable values to display the user name in the checkbox?

Comment: @Luiz your HTML doesn't change, you only need to append a condition (which you should already have), such as `*ngIf="myForm"`, to avoid error when your form isn't defined (which can happen, since in some cases, your store doesn't return values)

Comment: Okay, but my form has other fields too ... but can I create a method using the above logic to return an array of formControl as well?

Comment: @Luiz well that's something you should have precised ... You can use `myForm.addControl()` to add controls to your form, or if they don't rely on observables, you can simply add them in your builder call.